# Label with HTML content

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

How may I create a strongly-typed label with HTML content inside in MVC3?

```
<label for="nnn"><input type="checkbox" id="nnn" />Herp</label>
```

I have checked the code in the w3c validator and it seems to be valid, is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom HTML helper with `TagBuilder`.

Something like this (untested);

```
public static MvcHtmlString LabelCheckBoxFor<TModel>(
   this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
   Expression<Func<TModel,bool>> expression,
   string text)
{
   var labelTag = new TagBuilder("label");
   labelTag.MergeAttribute("for", "nnn"); 
   labelTag.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression) + text;
   return labelTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
}
```

Might not be 100% but you get the idea. I'm not sure how to pull the "for" value out of the model. You might need `FromLambdaExpression`, or another parameter.

And use it like this:

```
@Html.LabelCheckBoxFor(model => model.SomeField, "Herp")
```

Comment: I see, that is pretty cool. Do you know how can I set the "value" attribute so I can set the value back where there are validation problems? Thanks.

Comment: it works great, I changed the last line to MvcHtmlString.Create() But yes, your idea works great! Thanks a million.